# find all of rational solutions of the quartic equation?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Consider the equation $a^4+6v^2a^2-8a+v^4=0$ over the rationals. 
Note that the following are solutions: $(a,v)=(1,1),(0,0),(2,0)$. Are there any other rational solutions?

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but this can be rewritten as $(a^{2} + 3v^{2})^{2} = 8(v^{4}+a).$

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments.My general question is how we can determine the coefficients of a quartic equation(or higher degree eqtation) ax^4+bx^+cx^3+dx^2+e=0 such that it has rational solutions. A trivial method is first determine the roots (x_i), then  the coefficients!!!... I mean as example how I determine the coefficients a,b in the quartic equation 3x^4+2^x^3+ax^2+x+ b=0  such that it has the rational roots?

Comment: @user151553: There is no general algorithm to decide if a given quartic equation has a rational solution. This follows from Matiyasevich's theorem, because every system of polynomial equations can be encoded into a single quartic equation (using sums of squares of quadratic equations, including simple variable changes like $x=yz$).

Comment: For $y=v^2+3a^2$, the curve $y^2= 8a^4+8a$ is an elliptic curve; so it should not be hard to find its rank. If $0$, the answer is easy, otherwise one needs harder method for genus 3 curves.
What is the motivation for the question?

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich: That curve has rank 1. See my comment below Luis Ferroni's answer.

Comment: thank you very much for comments. if the above elliptic curve has positive rank, now how i can search  the solutions that for them  we  have v^2=y-3a^2(with v rational number)?

Comment: by letting $2/a=X$, $y/a^2=Y$, we get $Y^2=X^3+8$ with the rank=1. now note that $v^2=y-3a^2=4(Y-3)/X^2$, then $ Y-3(=t^2)$  must be square number.Thus by letting $Y=t^2+3$ in the equaion $Y^2=X^3+8$, the solution reduces to finding the rational solution in the equation $X^3=t^4+6t^2+1$? note that the solution $(t,X)=(0,1),(1,2),(-1,2)$ are trivial.... Now the question is Dose the equation any other  rational solution????

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete solution but rather a *line of action*. I think this method may work completely, but it is too tedious to make step by step.

Note that you can think of your equation as a quadratic with variable $v^2$. Said that, for $v^2$ to be rational, the discriminant of the quadratic has to be the square of a rational number, this is:

$$36a^4 - 4(a^4-8a)=\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^2$$
$$2a(a^3+1) = \left(\frac{m}{4n}\right)^2$$

Writing $a=\frac{p}{q}$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$, and replacing above:

$$2p(p^3+q^3) = \left(\frac{q^2m}{4n}\right)^2$$

Which in turn, since the LHS is an integer number, implies that $4n$ divides $q^2m$. Notice that:

$$d:=\gcd(p,p^3+q^3) = \gcd(p,q^3) = 1$$

In particular $d:=\gcd(2p,p^3+q^3)\in \{1,2\}$.

1. If $d=1$, then one has that $2p$ and $p^3+q^3$ have both to be
   squares of integers. Furthermore, notice that $p^3+q^3=(p+q)(p^2-pq+q^2)$,
   and also

   $$d':=\gcd(p+q,p^2-pq+q^2) \in \{1,3\}$$

   In any case, one has that $\frac{p+q}{d'}$ and $\frac{p^2-pq+q^2}{d'}$ have to be squares of integers. A bit of manipulation converts the equation $p^2-pq+q^2=u^2d'$, into the Pell equation with variables $x,y\in\mathbb{Q}$:
   $$ x^2 + 3y^2 = d'$$
   where $x=\frac{2p-q}{2u}$ and $y=\frac{q}{2u}$. If $d'=1$ it can be solved by standard methods. If $d'=3$ it is very similar.

   Once you've got the solutions of these Pell equations, you can parametrize all possible values of $p$ and $q$. Plugging them into our conditions that $\frac{p+q}{d'}$ and $2p$ had to be squares of integers, we will probably get a complete parametrization of the feasible couples $(p,q)$. This gives you all possible values of $a$ for this case.

   From them you get all possible rational values of $v^2$.
2. Its similar to Case 1, but with $d=2$. The steps should be similar (probably this one will require more care).

Comment: SAGE tells that your second display defines an elliptic curve, which is isomorphic to the one defined by $y^2=x^3+8$. SAGE also tells that this elliptic curve has infinitely many rational points. Relevant SAGE commands: "a, b = polygen(QQ, 'a, b')", "E = Jacobian(b^2-2*a^4-2*a)", "print E", "print E.mwrank()".

Comment: Thank you for the above comments. But I do not understsnd it completely..Does it yield a  solution to the problem?

Comment: Well I only guided you through a path that can be useful (at least to try to find other non-trivial solutions). It's up to you to fill the details and see if it works.